# Centering text on a header tag that has pseudo element

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTEmW/).

```
<h2><span>Some Text</span></h2>
```

I'm trying to vertically center the text inside my `h2` tag. I have tried playing with different heights, paddings, positions, and line-heights, but none of them seems to correctly position the text. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sTEmW/2/

I removed the superfluous span element:

```
h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #007480;

    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    line-height:30px;
}
h2:after {
    content: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/anh5c.png");
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 17px;
    float:right;
}
​
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I think I added the span because I thought I'd need a container for the pseudo element if I'm going to float it. But looks like it's working just fine without the additional markup.

Comment: @farjam Pseudo elements are actually placed **inside** of the element they are declared on, which isn't really intuitive. I assumed that was the reason you included it, because it is fairly logical to think you'd need to.

Comment: Just FYI, they seem to be broken in IE7.

Comment: I don't believe IE7 has native support for pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1):

As the solution from @Shmiddty works fine, this is an even simpler code and it works in all browsers, even IE7:

**HTML**

```
<h2>Our History</h2>​
```

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 67px 0 10px;
    background: #007480 url(http://i48.tinypic.com/anh5c.png) no-repeat right 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/5Z9fE/

Comment: Why didn't I think of using background images? :) This seems very clean.